# Can a credit company add 1000 to your account for not paying off your balance on time?

Tags: credit

Can a credit company add 1000. to your account and say it's because you didn't pay the original balance on time?

Comment: Can they charge interest and late fees? Absolutely.

Comment: Where are you? Consumer credit protection laws vary in different jurisdictions.

Comment: What to the terms of your credit card say? How high was the balance at the time (credit card interest rates are typically around 2-2.5% per month)? Does it specify interest vs late fees or something else?

Comment: What country/currency applies?

Comment: I wonder if it was an installment purchase on credit where you need to pay the full amount by a certain time or you end up owing all of the interest from the beginning plus possibly other fees.

Answer (score 2):

They can certainly do whatever you agreed to in the contract you signed when opening the account. For not making the minimum payment on time, the cost is typically some combination of late-payment fee and interest on the outstanding balance, and they may also increase the interest rate.

US$1000 would be unusually high for a late fee. It might be entirely reasonable for late fee plus interest, given that credit card interest rates start at unreasonable and go up to obscene.

Of course the querant didn't specify which currency this was. If that's 1000 Surinamese dollars, for example, it's currently about US$26, which is much closer to what I would expect the late fee to be.

If this is the first time in many years that you have missed a payment, contacting the bank and asking for forgiveness *may* result in their letting you skip the late fee. You will still owe interest, and they may or may not still increase the interest rate since you no longer have the perfect record that qualified you for the introductory rate.

Always read and understand the fine print before signing any contract. And do your darnedest to fully pay off credit cards every month rather than carrying a balance forward into the next month. If you're making a large purchase on the card, you may want to consider paying them back immediately rather than waiting for the bill to come due, to help protect against the risk of a large missed payment.

Comment: +1, although we don't know what currency the OP is being charged ("_$1000 would be unusually high_").

Comment: 1000 Turkish Liras would be obscenely low for a  late fee...

Comment: Good point about currency not having been stated. I have edited to emphasize this. Turns out that if it's Surinamese Dollars, the exchange rate would be about right for the US$25 I'd expect.